# Зависание кнопки клавиатуры vkbottle (vkapi)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, vkbottle

[image: зависание кнопки]
Здравствуйте! При использовании кнопки в вк появляется зависание кнопки (см.картинку). При этом никаких ошибок не происходит. Проблема решается только если перезайти в диалог с ботом. Помогите, пожалуйста! Код:

```
@bot.on.raw_event(GroupEventType.MESSAGE_EVENT, dataclass=MessageEvent)
async def handle_callback_event(event: MessageEvent):
    data = event.payload.get("action")
    print(msgid)
    if data == "menu":
       await event.send_message('Привет! Мы работаем с 10:00 до 02:00.\nВыбери нужное действие:',
                                           keyboard=keyboards.start_keyboard)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это **не зависание** и не проблема vkbottle. ВК ждёт, что будет запрос [messages.sendMessageEventAnswer](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.sendMessageEventAnswer), где можно показать сообщение или открыть ссылку, поэтому крутит этот спинер в течении ~30 секунд.

Насколько мне известно, если отправлять новую клавиатуру, кнопки меняются и этот спинер убирается (использовал такое в своих проектах). Но, так как у вас используется такая же клавиатура, кнопки не обновляется и, по всей видимости, получается такой артефакт.

В вашем случае, я думаю, лучше отправить обычный [`show_snackbar`](https://dev.vk.com/api/bots/development/keyboard#%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9).

```py
await event.show_snackbar("Привет! Мы работаем с 10:00 до 02:00.")
```

Чуть подробнее о Callback-кнопках в [документации ВК](https://dev.vk.com/api/bots/development/keyboard#Callback-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8).